# Selective installation by using NuGet Package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have created versions of NuGet packages,uploaded and it is working fine.
I have set of libraries in my package which has been populated in different directories inside the package.

Some users might require a particular directory of my NuGet package, and some of the libraries might not be needed. While installation I should prompt users that which part they need to install.

One Solution:Logical seperation of packages may be one solution. Like packing libraries in separate packages, and required packages can be installed.

But If it has been made selective installation, then it would be more easier. I have no idea whether NuGet have such an option. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet has support for framework versions and platforms using conventions, you can read up on them in the [docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Supporting_Multiple_.NET_Framework_Versions_and_Profiles). You can [group them by target framework version](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Grouping_Assemblies_by_Framework_Version) or [by target framework profile](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Grouping_Assemblies_by_Framework_Profile).

If you want to selectively install libraries, you are saying you want to selectively install **dependencies**: you should split them up in separate NuGet packages and declare your dependencies. These dependencies also can be [grouped](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies_in_version_2.0_and_above).

If your condition cannot be defined using framework version or profile, you should come up with your own entry-level NuGet packages and bring down the proper dependency chain (or use [PowerShell hooks](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal) for this).

Comment: Is there no way to prompt users for selective installation of libraries or others apart from this logical separation based on naming conventions and Framework versions?

Comment: User should pick the right package. And a package should be designed for a single purpose. You can deviate from it using the PowerShell hooks, but NuGet is not designed for this scenario as it is a package management tool, not a "software installer". Maybe you should check whether creating an MSI or something could be more suitable to support your case?